# VBA Excel Переменные

Tags: vba, excel

Есть задача, сделать переменную, значение которой - текст. Вывести этот текст нужно в другой книжке (файле), а потом с помощью нее, вызвать соответствующую рецептуру (которая вбита уже в книжке(н2))

Как это должно выглядеть:

Есть план продукции (книжка номер 1), который находится на сетевом диске
и, допустим, позиция 1 - название товара, позиция 2 количество которое будет выпущено.
Мне же надо, что бы в моей книжке (н2) отобразилась эти позиции, и рецептура, которая находится в моей книжке, а потом уже с помощью рецептуры, я должен посчитать, в чем я нуждаюсь, для производства.
Почему переменная, а не просто назначении ячейки которая равна другой ячейки, думаю вы уже поняли.
Прошу о помощи.

Answer (score 3):

Развернутый вариант без привлечения VBA с использованием `ВПР()`(«Не следует привлекать новые сущности без крайней на то необходимости»).

1. Создаем 2-е книги: `План продукции.xlsx`, `Рецептура.xlsx`;
2. Структура `План продукции.xlsx`:

[image: План продукции]

Содержит список продукции (`Продукция`) и её количество (`Количество`);

3. Структура `Рецептура.xlsx`

[image: Рецептура]

Содержит список внесенной продукции (`Продукция`) с количеством требуемых (`Кол-во на ед`) инградиентов (`Инградиенты`) для производства одной единицы продукции. Дополнительное поле для размерности инградиентов (`Измерение`).

Значение поля `Кол-во продукции` определяется с помощью функции `ВПР()` на основании книги `План продукции`. Формула `=ВПР(A2;'План продукции.xlsx'!$A$2:$B$4;2;ЛОЖЬ)`, где:

А2 - искомое значение. В нашем случае "Бисквит";

'План продукции.xlsx'!$A$2:$B$4 - книга в которой производится поиск искомого значения;

2 - номер столбца в таблице, из которого нужно вернуть значение;

ЛОЖЬ - точный поиск.

`Кол-во` - значение требуемого количества инградиентов определяется по формуле `=C2*E2`(`Кол-во на ед` * `Кол-во продукции`).

4. С помощью сводных таблиц на основании `Рецептура.xls` считаем например потребность в инградиентов.

[image: Сводная по количеству требуемых инградиентов]

Answer (score 2):

Только *VBA*? Если функциями листа - смотрите в сторону *ВПР()*